# Extracting json data using Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Got the script below that is using both the json and os modules. I have some tag compliance output in json format that I need to report on.

By using the below code it works fine when I'm focusing on just one output folder but the there are 8 in total. How do I looking inside each folder and pull out a particular value? As you can see below, inside of the lambda-tag-compliance folder I'm pulling out the values "FunctionName" and "Function Arn" from the resources.json. I need to look inside each of the 7 other folders which contain their own resources.json file. I'm guessing I'll need to create a list of the folder names but not sure how to incorporate that into what I already have below :-(

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, json

# this finds our json files
rootdir = "output"

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + file

        if filepath.endswith("resources.json") and "lambda-tag-compliance" in filepath:
            print (filepath)
            with open(filepath) as json_file:
                data = json.load(json_file)
                for key in data:
                  print('FunctionName : ' + key['FunctionName'])
                  print('FunctionArn: ' + key['FunctionArn'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like this. I just assumed the other compliance folders.

```
folders = ["lambda-tag-compliance1", "lambda-tag-compliance2", "lambda-tag-compliance3"]
rootdir = "output"
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for rec in files:
        full_filename = os.path.join(subdir, rec)
        if full_filename.endswith("resources.json"):
            if any(item in full_filename for item in folders):
                with open(full_filename) as json_file:
                    data = json.load(json_file)
                    for key in data:
                        print('FunctionName : ' + key['FunctionName'])
                        print('FunctionArn: ' + key['FunctionArn'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So RE getting more values out of the folders just add another print to the bottom of the existing code? Example - print('TableArn:' +)key['TableArn'])

Comment: yes correct. since you have opened the file and looping through each key; it would work. P.S don't forget to upvote the answer if it is correct

Comment: Ran the updated code, we don't get any errors but we also now don't get any output? We should see something like the below:                                                           [Container] 2019/11/18 17:08:52 Running command python dataextraction.py 
output/gf-dtv-development/eu-west-1/lambda-tag-compliance/resources.json 
FunctionName : TestSocketDisconnet 
FunctionArn: arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:392691546143:function:TestSocketDisconnet

Comment: @greghaines I kinda got lost what you really asked for. I have edited the code. The code loops through each of the subdirectories, and if the name ends with resourcesw.json, then it checks if it contains either of the values in the folder list. Only then it proceeds to pick the dictionary values.

Comment: No problem, really appreciate your help. I've just run the updated code but get the below error:           [Container] 2019/11/19 17:57:43 Running command python dataextraction4.py 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "dataextraction4.py", line 16, in <module> 
    print('FunctionName: ' + key['FunctionName']) 
KeyError: 'FunctionName' 
 
[Container] 2019/11/19 17:57:43 Command did not exit successfully python dataextraction4.py exit status 1 
[Container] 2019/11/19 17:57:43 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED

Comment: @greghaines that particular resources.json file does not seem to have a key "FunctionName". 

`KeyError: 'FunctionName'`